# Etymology of the Imperative

Tags: etymology

One thing I find interesting about the imperative in Italian is that in general for -are verbs the 2nd and 3rd person are swapped around (but only for -are verbs).

Present:

- Tu guardi
- Lui guarda

Imperative:

- (Tu) guarda!
- (Lui) guardi!

Does anyone know the origin of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The imperative is really second person only; the other forms are supplied by the subjunctive.

So the third person *guardi* is the same as the present subjunctive. The second person ending comes from Latin, notwithstanding *guardare* is not of Latin origin.

In the imperative, *amare* has *ama/amate* (same as Latin), *leggere* has *leggi/leggete* (*lege/legite*), *salire* has *sali/salite* (same as Latin).

In the present indicative, the Latin *amas* has become *ami*; the desinence *-i* is common for the second person in all conjugations. The present subjunctive of *amare* is *ami/ami/ami/amiamo/amiate/amino* (Latin *amem/ames/amet/amemus/ametis/ament*).